# Describe each of the following sets by listing its elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Slightly confused here:

$X = \{Na, \{b\}, \emptyset\}, Y = \{Na, b\}, Z = \{\emptyset\}$

How would I list the elements of:

1) $Y ∩ Z$

(the answer to this is "nothing" but how do I write that ?)

2) $(Z − X) ∪ Y = \{Na, b\}$

(Is this correct?, since $Z-X$ is nothing, so how do I write that?)

Comment: "Na" is just an element. A name like "bob"

Comment: The elements of $Y \cap Z$ are those elements that are both in $Y$ and in $Z$. But $Z$ has only one element : $\emptyset$, that is not listed in $Y$. Thus, $Y$ and $Z$ have no common elements, i.e. $Y \cap Z = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks, I just thought ∅ would be misleading since it appeared in Z..?

Comment: Yes, @aq1652 , the empty set appears *in* $Z$, so $Z$ itself is not empty. $\{\varnothing\}\neq \varnothing$  The purpose of these questions is (among other things) to ensure you understand that a set of one element is not just the element.  $\{b\}\neq b$ et cetera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > 1) $Y ∩ Z$
>
> (the answer to this is "nothing" but how do I write that ?)

The empty set is represented by $\{\,\}$ or $\varnothing$.

> > 2) $(Z − X) ∪ Y = \{Na, b\}$
>
> (Is this correct?, since Z-X is nothing, so how do I write that?)

This is correct.  $(Z-X)=\varnothing$ and $\varnothing\cup Y=Y$